# How to avoid javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: different object with the same identifier?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have small study project, something like quiz API. When I try to save complex object (Exam), hibernate throws EntityExistsException. I get REST request with dto (CreateExamRequestDto), then I map this dto to an Entity and save it using Spring Data JPA.

Here is my Entity classes:

EXAM ENTITY:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "exams", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
        "name",
        "category_id"
})})
public class Exam extends AbstractEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "exams_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "exams_seq_gen", sequenceName = "exams_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
    private Category category;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", nullable = false)
    private User owner;
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private List<Section> sections;
    @Column(name = "target_score", nullable = false)
    private Integer targetScore;
    @OneToMany()
    private List<ExamResult> results;

    @Transient
    private ExamResult result;

    //public constructor, getters, setters, hashcode and equals
}
```

SECTION ENTITY:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "exam_sections", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
        "name",
        "exam_id"
}))
public class Section extends AbstractEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "exam_sections_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "exam_sections_seq_gen", sequenceName = "exam_sections_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "question_weight", nullable = false)
    private Integer questionWeight;
    @Column(name = "target_questions", nullable = false)
    private Integer targetQuestions;
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private List<Question> questions;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "exam_id", nullable = false)
    private Exam exam;

    //public constructor, getters, setters, hashcode and equals
}
```

QUESTION ENTITY:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "questions")
public class Question extends AbstractEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "questions_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "questions_seq_gen", sequenceName = "questions_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "text", nullable = false)
    private String text;
    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private QuestionType type;
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private List<Answer> answers;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "section_id")
    private Section section;

    //public constructor, getters, setters, hashcode and equals
}
```

ANSWER ENTITY:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "answers")
public class Answer extends AbstractEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "answers_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "answers_seq_gen", sequenceName = "answers_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "text", nullable = false)
    private String text;
    @Column(name = "correct", nullable = false)
    private Boolean correct;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id", nullable = false)
    private Question question;

    //public constructor, getters, setters, hashcode and equals
}
```

And code that save it all:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public ExamShortDto createExam(CreateExamRequestDto request) {
    Exam exam = examMapper.mapToEntity(request, user);
    exam = examRepository.save(exam);             <<----- HERE

    return examMapper.mapToShortDto(exam);
}
```

On pointed line I've got next exception:

2017-09-05 17:24:12.278 ERROR 14024 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Forwarding to error page from request [/api/exam] due to exception [A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [org.yvasylchuk.testit.domain.entity.exam.Answer#191]; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [org.yvasylchuk.testit.domain.entity.exam.Answer#191]]

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [org.yvasylchuk.testit.domain.entity.exam.Answer#191]; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [org.yvasylchuk.testit.domain.entity.exam.Answer#191]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:395) ~[spring-orm-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:226) ~[spring-orm-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:499) ~[spring-orm-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:216) ~[spring-tx-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153) ~[spring-tx-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:134) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.RC2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.RC2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.0.RC3.jar:5.0.0.RC3]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.yvasylchuk.testit.service.exam.impl.ExamFacadeImpl.createExam(ExamFacadeImpl.java:143) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]

    ......

Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [org.yvasylchuk.testit.domain.entity.exam.Answer#191]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:771) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1.cascade(JpaPersistEventListener.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:383) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:491) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:423) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:386) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:445) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:804) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:771) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1.cascade(JpaPersistEventListener.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:383) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:491) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:423) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:386) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:445) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:804) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:771) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1.cascade(JpaPersistEventListener.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:383) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:491) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:423) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:386) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:445) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:780) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:765) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
    ...
```

SOLUTION:

I just change one line in Answers Entity from:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "answers_seq_gen")
HERE -->> @SequenceGenerator(name = "answers_seq_gen", sequenceName = "answers_id_seq")
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
```

to:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "answers_seq_gen")
HERE -->> @SequenceGenerator(name = "answers_seq_gen", sequenceName = "answers_id_seq", allocationSize = 200)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
```

Comment: Do your `id`(s) columns in your database have AUTO_INCREMENT  enabled or something similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**What is really happening:** since you are cascading your answers and since the relation is OneToMany then it is possible that you are having many answers whic exceeds the default value of the allocation size, the sequence generator has attribute allocation size which indicates the number of the possibles increments in the transaction so if the limit exceeded you will end up having duplicate in your id.

**Solution:** you can change your generator to auto or increate the allocation size

Comment: Thanks, you save a lot of my time!